# How to provide default implementations in C++ 20 using concepts?

Tags: c++, oop, interface, c++20, c++-concepts

I am experimenting the possibility of using `concept`s introduced in C++20 as static interfaces. So far, I am doing well except that I am unable to figure out a way to provide a "default implementation" for a concept.

For example, I have a concept named `ByteBuffer`, and it is stated like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept ByteBuffer = requires (T t) {
  { t.read_byte() } noexcept -> std::convertible_to<uint8_t>;
  { t.has_byte() } noexcept -> std::same_as<bool>;

  /* default implementation for `t.read_until(...)`? */
};
```

I should be able to, logically, provide a default implementation for `t.read_until(...)` (parameters omitted), and allow concrete implementations to override the default one. Is there a way? How can I do it?

If this is not possible, I think it is reasonable to add such an ability.

Currently, I have to resort to the CRTP to provide a facade class, and I think it more redundant than I could conceive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Concepts are *not* base classes. In fact, concepts have no explicit or implicit relation to any of their template arguments.

Concepts do precisely one thing: verify whether a particular set of template parameters is appropriate to use when instantiating a particular template. That's *all*.

Concepts contain a sequence of expressions and terms that ought to be valid for the given template parameters. That's all that is needed to determine if a set of template parameters is valid for a particular use, so that's all concepts provide.

If you need some kind of default functionality, you will have to use alternate C++ mechanisms to do that. The simplest being a utility function that has its own constraint:

```
template<typename T>
concept ByteBufferReadUntil = ByteBuffer<T> &&
  requires(T bb) //Add parameters as appropriate
  {
    { t.read_until() } noexcept -> std::same_as<bool>;
  };

template<ByteBuffer T>
  requires ByteBufferReadUntil<T>
bool read_byte_buffer_until(T &bb)
{
  return t.read_until();
}

template<ByteBuffer T>
bool read_byte_buffer_until(T &bb)
{
  //default implementation for `t.read_until(...)`
}
```

So whenever you want to do `read_until` for an arbitrary `ByteBuffer`, you call `read_byte_buffer_until`.

Comment: Couldn't you simply use `if constexpr` in this case? What is the tipping point when deciding to go from a `if constexpr` construction to writing a bunch of functions?

Answer (score 7):

Concepts are really just constraints on types, so it doesn't make sense to add a "default implementation" to a concept. Instead, what you can do is to provide a default implementation for `read_until`, and use that unless some `ByteBuffer` type provides its own implementation.

First you can write a separate concept that checks for `read_until`:

```
template <typename T>
concept Readable = requires (T t) {
 { t.read_until() } noexcept -> std::same_as<void>;  // takes no arguments, and returns void for demonstration
};
```

and then you can provide a default implementation for types that don't provide this function:

```
template <typename T>
void read_until_impl(T t) {
   std::cout << "default implementation";
}

template <Readable T>
void read_until_impl(T t) {
    t.read_until();  // call provided member function
}
```

and then some function that uses a `ByteBuffer` type could call the function like this:

```
template <ByteBuffer T>
void use(T t) {
    read_until_impl(t);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7q7cG1).

Comment: You should probably constrain "Readable" with `ByteBuffer`, as well as the various `read_until` implementations.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see what you're saying, but I'm actually relying on only functions such as `use` that are already constrained to `ByteBuffer` types to call `read_until_impl`. Is it still better to constrain `read_until_impl` as well?

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, C++20 Concepts really don't provide any mechanism to help with this problem at all. They're *just* predicates that constrain templates. *Nothing* more.

What I'll offer instead is a more concise alternative: use `if constexpr`:

```
template <ByteBuffer BB>
void read_until(BB& buffer) {
    if constexpr (requires { buffer.read_until(); }) {
        buffer.read_until();
    } else {
        while (buffer.has_byte()) {
            buffer.read_byte();
        }
    }
}
```

Or sometimes I like using function composition to make this clearer, using something like [Boost.Hof](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/first_of.html):

```
auto read_until = first_of(
    [](ByteBuffer auto& bb) requires requires { bb.read_until(); } {
        // specialized impl
    },
    [](ByteBuffer auto& bb) {
        // default impl
    });
```

This can be `overload` too, since one is more constrained than the other, I just like using `first_of` since it just makes it that much clearer (and plus would work in C++17 with just a trailing-return-type-based constraint).

Comment: Yeah! The first method is actually what I am using now!

Answer (score 1):

Concepts are not base classes. In fact, concepts have no explicit or implicit relation to any of their template arguments.

Concepts do precisely one thing: verify whether a particular set of template parameters is appropriate to use when instantiating a particular template. That's all.

Concepts contain a sequence of expressions and terms that ought to be valid for the given template parameters. That's all that is needed to determine if a set of template parameters is valid for a particular use, so that's all concepts provide.

If you need some kind of default functionality, you will have to use alternate C++ mechanisms to do that. The simplest being a utility function that has its own constraint:

```
template<typename T>
concept ByteBufferReadUntil = ByteBuffer<T> &&
  requires(T bb) //Add parameters as appropriate
  {
    { t.read_until() } noexcept -> std::same_as<bool>;
  };

template<ByteBuffer T>
  requires ByteBufferReadUntil<T>
bool read_byte_buffer_until(T &bb)
{
  return t.read_until();
}

template<ByteBuffer T>
bool read_byte_buffer_until(T &bb)
{
  //default implementation for `t.read_until(...)`
}
```

So whenever you want to do read_until for an arbitrary ByteBuffer, you call read_byte_buffer_until.